# Triggering an AWS API from a web page and returning SQL query results

Tags: jquery, html, mysql, ajax, aws-api-gateway

I have configured an AWS Data API that successfully invokes a Lambda function (which interacts with an RDS database) and returns JSON sqlStatementResults. A test query and result are below:

Query Strings > query:

```
{sqlStatement="SELECT * FROM Table"}
```

[image]

[image]

I am now trying to set up the final piece of this process: interactions with the API from a public URL; I have an index.html page hosted in an S3 bucket, into which I would like users to be able to type a SQL query (in some sort of search bar element) and click a "Query" button (presumably a button element), triggering an API request using the specified SQL query (presumably jQuery AJAX method), and returning the API response contents in another output element (just a string of text for now could be fine, although ideally a Bootstrap DataTable). I am unsure how to go about this.

Here is a demonstration of what the web page would look like (SQL query input, click Query button, API request made via jQuery function with AJAX GET method using AWS API Gateway API endpoint, sending the input query to Lambda --> RDS, query results to Lambda --> API --> replace "This is a test box..." on web page?):

[image]

Comment: Where have you reached so far? Are you able to get response for Query in UI and asking for how to load response in Datatable

or Not able to get response yet

Comment: @MyTwoCents not able to get a response yet -- wondering how I construct the HTML/JavaScript to get the response and write it to the web page